# How to test content loaded by AJAX in rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cucumber

I have a select whose contents are filled in based on the selection of another select.

I have verified that it works by using it myself. However, I'm having trouble testing it.

Here's the test I have:

```
    @javascript
    When(/^I submit the form$/) do
        page.select @professor.name, from: 'Professor'
        page.fill_in 'title', with: "Test"
        page.fill_in 'content', with: "Test"
        sleep 5.seconds
        binding.pry
        page.click_button 'Submit'
    end
```

In the pry session, when I query the contents of the select box with `page.find('#course').text` it returns `""`. In the test, the contents of the select box aren't being loaded.

The javascript is simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#professor').on('change', function() {
    id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    path = window.location.origin + '/professors/' + id + '/courses';

    $.ajax(path, {
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#course').empty();
        data.forEach(function(course) {
          $('#course').append(
            '<option value=' + course.id + '>'
            + course.identifier + ': ' + course.name
            + '</option>'
          );
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sleep in ajax tests is not reliable. It makes your test suite slower and does not give guarantee that it will work anyway.

Check out this article https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

The idea it that you should check page for existing of required element, and if it is not present yet, then you should wait again for some amount of time(but not 5 seconds!)